How to apply the Manipulate function on a 5D data set and visualize the data using ListContourPlot?
Say you have a data set with 5 columns and each column is defined by the variables theta, phi, x, y, z such that data(theta, phi, x, y, z).
I would like to use the Manipulate function on this list and use the ListContourPlot function to visualise data such that theta is along the horizontal axis, phi is along the vertical axis, the value of the contour plot is given by the value z. I would like to have the x and y values as slide bars. I've given it a go but I have had no luck. Below is my not so good attempt. It would be great if someone could tell me why it fails.
data ={{0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 1.}, {0.01, 30.01, 0, 0, 0.499698}, {0.01, 60.01, 
  0, 0, 0.500302}, {0.01, 90.01, 0, 0, 1.}, {0.01, 120.01, 0, 0, 
  0.499698}, {0.01, 150.01, 0, 0, 0.500302}, {0.01, 180.01, 0, 0, 
  1.}, {0.01, 210.01, 0, 0, 0.499698}, {0.01, 240.01, 0, 0, 
  0.500302}, {0.01, 270.01, 0, 0, 1.}, {0.01, 300.01, 0, 0, 
  0.499698}, {0.01, 330.01, 0, 0, 0.500302}};

Manipulate[
 ListContourPlot[data[[All, {1, 2, 5}]], 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \(2\)]\)", 
     Medium, Bold, White], 
    Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Phi]\), \(2\)]\)", Medium, Bold, 
     White]}, {PlotStyle -> Thick, AxesStyle -> Thick}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, White, Medium], ImageSize -> 400, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 3, ContourLabels -> All, 
  ContourStyle -> {Magenta, Dashed}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], {{data[[x, {3}]], 90}, 0, 180,
   1}, {{data[[y, {4}]], 180}, 0, 360, 1}]
```


Your "Manipulate" has wrong syntax. The variables should be defined as: {symbol,min,max}. Read the help.

Note the SE-approved way to mark a question solved is to accept the answer that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! Do put "[SOLVED]" in the title.

Thanks Michael E2. I have to wait 16 hours but I will do so. Cheers.

With the assistance of ChatGPT, I successfully resolved the challenge of displaying a subset of a list using ListContourPlot. Below is the solution.
Assume you have a list structured as follows:
data = {{a1, b1, c1, d1, e1}, {a2, b2, c2, d2, e2}, ...., {an, bn, cn, dn, en}}.
where the values of "cn" and "dn" are integers greater than or equal to zero. The values of "cn" and "dn" increase in steps defined by stepSizeCol3 and stepSizeCol4, respectively.
The following code snippet creates a contour map for selected values of "cn" and "dn" using the Manipulate slider. The slider for "cn" is labeled as value1, and for "dn", it's labeled as value2. The contour plot illustrates the values of "an" along the horizontal axis, "bn" along the vertical axis, and the values of en determine the contour plot's appearance.
stepSizeCol3 = 30;
stepSizeCol4 = 30;

Manipulate[Module[{selectedData},
  selectedData = Select[data, #[[3]] == value1 && #[[4]] == value2 &];
  ListContourPlot[selectedData[[All, {1, 2, 5}]], 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["Column 1", Bold, 14], 
     Style["Column 2", Bold, 14]}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Contour Plot of Selected Data", 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic]], {{value1, 0}, Min[data[[All, 3]]], 
  Max[data[[All, 3]]], stepSizeCol3}, {{value2, 0}, 
  Min[data[[All, 4]]], Max[data[[All, 4]]], stepSizeCol3}]

